# running old msdos/windows program qa4 ver 4.0 on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, wine, windows-xp, dosbox, ms-dos

Looking for more info on this because I'm not sure how to qualify my qa4 v4.0 program (symantic). It runs on ms-dos, but also runs as a windows program in win3, 98, xp. It won't run under win7.

I have heard about programs like dosbox for games, and wine for windows programs but totally confused which way to go. I have a new system76 kudu pro system running ubuntu 13.10, and I just don't want to screw it up with mindless experimenting.

I especially hope someone here is aware of qa4. It has been my backbone for 20 years, but I'v had it with microsloth.

Hope y'all can shed some light into my darkened closet!
t

Answer (score 0):

According to [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q&A_(Symantec)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q&A_%28Symantec%29), Q&A by Symantec has been superseded by Sesame Database Manager (Lantica Software, LLC).

Thus, I recommend to give a try for the trial of Sesame Database Manager, as it also supports Linux, http://lantica.com/Support/downloads.html

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but i'm well aware of the 'new' q&a and it's history, and trust me, it doesn't hold a candle to the original for my purposes. What i need to do is rid myself and my 'friends' of the 800 lb gorilla standing in the middle of the room. that's why i'm here with ubuntu on my lap, trying to find solutions. again, thanks for the reply.  t